# Some beginner questions about Centreon

Tags: plugins, monitoring

I am new to Centreon and I have a few questions I need to figure out. I have these services:

[image: service 1]

[image: service 2]

I just want to know how can I have these services like this.

**2nd question**

on *Github*, I find that the plugin is end with .pm not .pl, which is I wonder why, and how to use the plugin on *Github*, because I already put it in on a folder on Centreon and restart it on the poller, but I do not see the plugin I downloaded.

**3rd question**

> For interfaces:
>
> --plugin=os::linux::snmp::plugin --mode=interfaces --add-status --add-traffic
>
> For services (if it's windows):
>
> --plugin=os::windows::snmp::plugin

Is this just command or I have to modify it on a plugin ?

Comment: If you have three questions, then you should probably ask them in different posts.

Comment: I ask 3 questions because these 3 related to each others, further more I don't want to post many posts at the same time.

Comment: I don't mean to be harsh, your questions might have a common theme, but they are not very related.

Comment: ye, well, just consider me a noob, and I just want to know how to get it works, because I google many days already, and still got nothing

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: thanks for the reminding me, will notice next time

Answer (score 0):

1. You must have create a new host and link to this host an host template. This host template is linked to services and this why you have services created. Do not hesitate to check this [documentation](https://documentation.centreon.com/docs/centreon/en/19.04/quick_start/add_host_from_template.html)
2. To use our centreon plugin you have two different way to do:
   Clone our GitHub repository [Here](https://github.com/centreon/centreon-plugins), and manage your script file by file use the centreon_plugins.pl to call the .pm file through the --plugin option, through the following command line you can download the repo:

   ```
    git clone https://github.com/centreon/centreon-plugins.git
   ```

   Use the Centreon RPM packages, who they correspond to the GitHub script, but all build per kind of devices (one .pl script per devices). You can install them with the following command line:

   ```
   yum install --nogpgcheck centreon-plugins\*
   ```

   By default all nagios plugins are stored in "/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/" and the centreon plugins are stored in "/usr/lib/centreon/plugins/"
3. '--plugin' option is related to a command and it just indicate the plugin that will be used, you don't need to modify any plugin just the command unless you want to change something inside the plugin.